# Доступ к элементам DOM в функции javaScript

Tags: javascript, функции, события

Добрый день! Подскажите, где я не понимаю. Пишу функцию на событие (Нажатия кнопки). Функция должна выводить текст на страницу html. Однако ничего не происходит. Alertом все выводится.

```js
function adding() {

  var name = document.getElementById('new');
  name.innerHTML = "fdkk;fdl";

  // 
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Forma</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_f.css">

</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <aside>
      <div id="new"></div>
    </aside>
    <form>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить" id="button" onclick="adding()"></p>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my_script.js"></script>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Чтобы страница не обновлялась, можно в событие клика дописать: **onclick="adding(); return false"**

Answer (score 3):

Текст вставляется. Просто у вас указан **type**=*"submit"*, и при нажатии на кнопку страница перезагружается. Вы просто не успеваете заметить результат.

```js
function adding() {
  var name = document.getElementById('new');
  name.innerHTML = "fdkk;fdl";
};
```

```html
  <article>
    <aside>
      <div id="new"></div>
    </aside>
    <form>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Отправить" id="button" onclick="adding()">
      </p>
    </form>
  </article>
```

Или же использовать вот такой хак:

```js
function adding(event) {
  var name = document.getElementById('new');
  name.innerHTML = "fdkk;fdl";
};
```

```html
<article>
  <aside>
    <div id="new"></div>
  </aside>
  <form>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить" id="button" onclick="event.preventDefault(); adding();">
    </p>
  </form>
</article>
```